# jquery sortable with connectwith. event for just internal sorting?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a series of connected lists, and I would like to fire two separate events:

1. an event when I re-order a list without moving elements between lists.
2. an event when I move an element from one list to another.

I see that the sortable has `update` and `stop` which seem to answer #1, and `receive` which handles case #2. The issues is that `update` and `stop` are both *also* called when a list receives an element from another list. I would like an event that is fired in case #1 exclusively. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the sortable from which the item has originated in the ui.sender property of the stop function

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
      console.log('item originated from', ui.sender);
  }
});
```

for more information check this [api link of jquery sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop)